# Tag OF in 32 bit register multiplication

Tags: assembly, product

I've a problem with product in Assembly. I want to multiplicate two matrixes with dimensions, ad exemplum, 1raw x 1column. 
If result is bigger than 2^15 IMUL sets the flag OF=1 beacuse of the overflaw, but i don't  understand why, infact i'm using 32 bit register and not 16 bit. Here is some code to explain this problem, for example:

```
short int mat1[] = {-70};
short int mat2[] = {20000};

__asm {
        lea eax, mat1
        lea ebx, mat2
        xor edx, edx
        xor ecx, ecx
        movsx esi, [eax][ecx*2]  //esi = 70
        imul esi, [ebx][edx*2]   //multiplicates esi for mat2 that is 20000
}
```

Now esi is 0022A340h instead of FFFFFDDD20h(-140000), and the flag OF=1, why? The result is same with numbers instead of matrixes, but i'm working with them and i'm not sure if it's irrilevant, so i've posted mat1 and mat2 in this example.

Comment: Since you are using imul with 32 bit register, the memory reference is also 32 bit instead of 16bit. As a result the second operand is not 20000 but something else (depending on what happens to be the next 2 bytes after mat2)

Comment: If i wirte "mov edx, [ebx]", then edx is CCCC4E20. So what should i do to have the right result? I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sign-extend the second operand as well:

```
short int mat1[] = {-70};
short int mat2[] = {20000};

__asm {
        lea eax, mat1
        lea ebx, mat2
        xor edx, edx
        xor ecx, ecx
        movsx esi, WORD PTR[eax][ecx*2]  //esi = 70
        movsx edi, WORD PTR[ebx][edx*2] 
        imul esi, edi
}
```

or just do 16-bit multiplication (will return 32bit result in dx:ax)

```
__asm {
        lea esi, mat1
        lea edi, mat2
        xor edx, edx
        xor ecx, ecx
        mov ax, [esi][ecx*2]  //esi = 70
        imul WORD PTR[edi][edx*2] 
        // result is now in dx:ax
}
```

Comment: There something wrong, or that dosn't work in my code: "movsx edi, [ebx]" set edi = 00000020h instead of 4E20h... And with the 16-bit imul, ax is A340 and DX is 0. And in eax there are some bit modified at the left of AX.

Comment: Fixed 32bit version. I was missing `WORD PTR`. Without it the compiler does not know if it should sign extend the byte or the word at esi (or edi)

Comment: Fixed 16 bit version as well. `imul ax,{r/m}` is not the same as `imul {r/m}`. The former will do 16 bit multiplication and truncate the result to 16 bits. while the latter will do 8x8=16 or 16x16=32 or 32x32=64 bit multiplication between al, ax or eax and the operand and put the result in ax, dx:ax or edx:eax (based on the size of the operand).

Comment: Great! Thanks, it works perfectly. I 've done some push and pop because all registers were occupied. I choose the 32-bit version that was more similar to my previous code. If i understand WORD PTR in MUL/IMUL in this case is almost like MOVSX. I mean... it tells compiler how much to extend result if it' shorter than the base register... isn't it?